# Writing to an XML file using standard microsoft libraries

Tags: c#, html, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write values into an XML file using this function. I am retaining the value under sql_connection, but am receiving the error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I understand what the error means, but I do not know how to work with XML files. How should I approach this problem? When I step through my code it stops at myNode.Value = sql_connection; It says I am returning a null value, but sql_connection sees the value I entered on my admin page. Thanks in advance.

```
    public void SAVEsqlConnection(string sql_Connection)
    {
        XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        myXmlDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml");


        XmlNode root = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/connectionString");
        myNode.Value = sql_Connection;
        myXmlDocument.Save("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml");
    }
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
    public void SAVEsqlConnection(string sql_Connection)
    {
        XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        myXmlDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml");

        string connectionStringXPath = "/ConnectionStrings/add[@connectionString=\"{0}\"]";
        connectionStringXPath = string.Format(connectionStringXPath, sql_Connection);

        XmlNode node = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(connectionStringXPath);
        node.Attributes["ConnectionStrings"].Value = sql_Connection;

        myXmlDocument.Save("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml");
    }
```

Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--This is to write the connection string-->
-<ConnectionStrings> <add connectionString="asdf" Name="sqlConnection1"/>  </ConnectionStrings>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like `myNode` is null, not `sql_Connection`.  Please show your sample xml as well, it seems like your `.SelectSingleNode` isn't returning anything.

Comment: Agreed.  Too bad he didn't include what line the error occurred on.   Then we wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: You are looking like making configuration file. you can use Configuration, configuration section e.t.c classes to make those config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to do something like:

```
            XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

            myXmlDocument.Load(@"..\..\XMLFile1.xml");

            XmlNode root = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement;

            //We only want to change one connection. 
            //This could be removed if you just want the first connection, regardless of name.
            var targetKey = "sqlConnection1";

            //get the add element we want
            XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("add[@Name = '{0}']", targetKey));

            var sql_Connection = "some sql connection";

            //set the value of the connectionString attribute to the value we want
            myNode.Attributes["connectionString"].Value = sql_Connection;

            myXmlDocument.Save(@"..\..\XMLFile2.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you Gerrard. My fault to everyone for not supplying what line the error was on.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPATH value is incorrect.

```
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/connectionString");
```

In the line above `myNode` is null because method `SelectSingleNode` **returns** The first XmlNode that matches the XPath query or **null if no matching node is found** and there is no node that contains that XPATH.  Looks like a typo where you left off the "s" in ConnectionStrings (or think that you can use an attribute name like an element [node] name

In your second example the XPATH needs to resolve to

```
"/ConnectionStrings/add[@connectionString='asdf']"
```

Again, it looks like you have a typo where you are using quotes(") instead of ticks(') in your expression.

If you are looking for the attributes of the add `element` then your XPATH expression would be `/ConnectionStrings/add` and then you can get the attributes of that node.  This assumes that you have given us the XML from the root node.  You may want to look at this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

You have another typo once you get past the null issue of the `XmlNode`.

```
node.Attributes["ConnectionStrings"].Value = sql_Connection;
```

in the XML example above the attribute name is `connectionString` not `ConnectionStrings` so you will need to change the above line to.

```
node.Attributes["connectionString"].Value = sql_Connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
node.Attributes["**ConnectionStrings**"].Value = sql_Connection;
```

should be in the exact casing as in the Xml.  Xml is case-sensitive